# Marketing Cloud: Import from Salescloud Record Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, import, email-studio

I'm trying to setup a test Salesforce Data Extension that's being built from a report based on my test records in Salescloud.

The Salescloud report currently contains 20 or so records with the following columns:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Lead Source
- Lead ID

I've setup the import under Interactions > Import to pull from the Salescloud report.

All fields are selected on the import and I have Lead ID as the key field and email defined as email. All the others are text fields.

I run the import and get a notification that it's completed but every time it shows 0 updates or inserts.

I'm able to import other reports without an issue. I'm sure there's something super obvious that I'm missing but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: What did the email notification you got post import say?

Comment: The following import has completed successfully ...
Results:

 Inserted: 0
 Updated: 0

Comment: Are there new or modified records in the report, not already imported ? Also, what is the import mode : add only, add & update or update only ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any modified records in the report. It's a fairly basic report that just looks for all my accounts with TEST in the name. I've been using add & update as the update import mode - but there are not records in the data extension as of yet, so in theory it should only add.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know what was causing the issue but I rebuilt the report with the same data fields and it started working right away.